# MATLAB 3D sliding window on a volume

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, sliding-window

I have a `M`x`N`x`D` volume and I need a `l`x`h`x`w` sliding window that goes through all the voxels of the volume. In each sliding window I need to compute the [Root Mean Square Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#RMS_contrast). Which is the smarter way to do it?

I would like to limit the use of `for` loops because the volume is pretty big, 1024x1024x146.

Comment: What operations do you want to do on these voxels? Just to be clear, by sliding window you mean that you want to move the window by one row (or column/plane) for each operation such that it will overlap the previous window.

Comment: I have to compute the Root Mean Square Contrast [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28vision%29] for each window. Yes, each time the window shifts of one voxel in one of the three directions, thus the next window overlaps the previous.

Comment: Does the 3D window happen to be [multiplicatively separable](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_separable_function)?

Comment: I don't think that in this specific case my problem is multiplicatively separable‌​ but this can be useful for me in other cases. Only to be sure to have understood correctly, if my function was multiplicatively separable‌​ I could apply the function separately in the x,y,z directions and then sum together the result (e.g. to compute the gradient magnitude I can apply the window first along the rows and then along the columns)?

Comment: Did you consider using `convn`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html

Comment: I don't think it is possible to compute the RMS contrast with a convolution, I thought about that but I didn't find the solution otherwise `convn` would be great.

Comment: What is the RMS contrast? I didn't know that's what you were trying to compute. Your problem statement doesn't make reference to this in any way. Please update your question to illuminate what exactly you're doing within the sliding windows.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to divide into voxels that are `l` x `h` x `w`. If this is the case and assuming your matrix is called `q` where `size(q) = [M, N, D]`.

```
function N = test(q, l, h, w)
    qPrime = mat2cell(q, ...
        [l*ones(1, floor(size(q,1)/l)), mod(size(q,1), l)], ...
        [h*ones(1, floor(size(q,2)/h)), mod(size(q,2), h)], ...
        [w*ones(1, floor(size(q,3)/w)), mod(size(q,3), w)]);

    N = cellfun(@RMS, qPrime, 'uni', 0);
end

function N = RMS(M)
    var = M - mean(M(:));
    N = sqrt(sum(var(:).^2)) ./ numel(M);
end
```

This makes a cell array with each voxel in a cell. Apply the function to each voxel using `cellfun(@foo, qPrime, 'uni', 0)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I want to do. Your solution works great to split the volume, but I need a 3d convolution between the `l`x`h`x`q` window and the volume and each time the central voxel of the window gets the value computed using the root mean square contrast.

Comment: Isn't the window `l` x `h` x `w`? And what do you mean by a 3D convolution? That doesn't seem at all like the RMS contrast.

Comment: I didn't explain well. I need to create a 3D map where each voxel contains the value of the RMS contrast compute over a neighbourhood of `l`x`h`x`w`. Theorically the sliding window have to shift of a voxel for each iteration but this is what I would like to avoid because in that case `for` loops would be repeat more than 150 millions of times.

Comment: So you want the output to be `M` x `N` x `D`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need a `M`x`N`x`D` output matrix!

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this specific problem using the `stdfilt` function of MATLAB because the Root Mean Square Contrast is the standard deviation of the pixel intensities inside the sliding window. The `stdfilt`function allows you to define a

> multidimensional array of zeros and ones where the nonzero elements specify the neighbors. (MATLAB Help)